# Issue in Asynchronous task handling by Celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery, flask-wtforms

I am new to Flask ,as part of POC I am building a web app which takes some input and runs a long python program (it takes 3-4 hours) to run based on the user input.Now I read that I should use celery so that user need not wait for a response  from my program , which would take a lot of time , instead I can redirect them to some page .

So here is my attempt at calling my long process via Celery

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from forms import LoginForm
from test_webapp import testing_webapp
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'This is secret key'
celery = Celery(app.name, broker= 'amqp://localhost//')

@celery.task
def call_demographic_data(brand,start_date,end_date,Country):
    '''
    This is a really long process
    '''
    testing_webapp(brand,start_date,end_date,Country)


@app.route('/index',methods=[ 'GET','POST'])
def index():
    return "Query Submitted successfully"

@app.route('/',methods=[ 'GET'])
@app.route('/input',methods=[ 'GET','POST'])
def input():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        call_demographic_data.delay(form.brand.data,form.startdate.data,form.enddate.data,form.Country.data)
        return redirect('/index')
    return render_template('input.html', title='Enter a Brand', form=form)
    #return ("should return index page")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but when I run my python script , nothing happens to interface, it is kind of stuck, it should have been redirected to index page (the one which shows that query has been successfully submitted)

Below is the console (Anaconda Prompt o/p)

```
(base) C:\Users\aadhikarla\Insight Auomation\app>python standard_routes.py
 * Serving Flask app "standard_routes" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 908-258-463
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2019 12:47:14] "GET /input HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It does not move forward from the GET request , I had changed the long program to just few print statements for testing celery , but it is not happening at all.

Also It is my understanding that by using Celery  even if the user closes the browser , the Job will still persist and not stop , please let me know if my inference is correct as well